# objc/c++ dyld_get_image_header function hooking load executable mach header by path

Tags: c++, c, xcode, hook

So im currently testing to hook this function:

```
const mach_header* dyld_get_image_header(uint32_t image_index){ ... }
```

I successfully achieved the hooking technique for this specific function, Now my main question is this:

Lets say, I have a binary executable file in some path we call it "Original", And currently I have another executable that is executed called "Fake" if you use `uint32_t dyld_image_count(void)` it would return all the image counts and this "Fake" executable would be at index = 1,
so if i want to use `dyld_get_image_header(1)` it would return the macho header of the executed "Fake" at index = 1 lets call it `fake_ret`,
Now my purpose is to replace this `fake_ret` with "Original" executable which is at some path,

So my question is, How can I load the original executable as const mach_header* like the function return by path so I can assign it to the `fake_ret?`

**pseudocode idea:**

```
const mach_header* dyld_get_image_header_hook(uint32_t image_index){

const mach_header* fake_ret = dyld_get_image_header_org(image_index);

if(image_index == 1){
     fake_ret = original // this is the original file inside some path which i cant know to make the assignment for it
      return fake_ret;
   }
return fake_ret;
   }
```

ofcourse the used _org function is just a pointer to the original function of the dyld get image header and takes as parameter and return same as i described,

so how can i load the original file to that assignment in the pseudocode is there any idea for this process?

Comment: When you say _"original file"_ do you mean the original `struct mach_header*`? If so, what's preventing you from `if(image_index == 1) return dyld_get_image_header(image_index);`

Comment: @TedLyngmo
No its just some other executable file saved in a path, I dont have its actual struct mach_header* ,  I just know its path lets say "/Library/Original" , this file is not actually mapped with any image_index.

Comment: Ok, but the function is expected to return a `const struct mach_header*`, so what do you do with this file? Do you open it and put the content in a  `struct mach_header`? Is the content of the file a binary representation of a `struct mach_header`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo
My hook function returns the fake_ret for any index as parameter, but when the index == 1 i would like to change assignment for this fake_ret for the file that is in this path "/Library/Original" but i dont know how to convert this file to a const struct mach_header* so the assignment would be okay.

Comment: A file is just a collection of bytes. What does the file contain? Is it, or is it not, in a format that can be used to populate a [`struct mach_header`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-792/EXTERNAL_HEADERS/mach-o/loader.h)? Is it perhaps a mach object file already?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Its the same file that is mapped at index == 1 but with no edits inside as the current mapped file is the same as the Original but with few edits inside, its an executable ELF, it can normally get executed and work, its an actual library file.

Comment: Is this a C or C++ question?

Comment: @Chris obj-c/c++

Comment: @TedLyngmo any suggestions? im still stuck on this.

Comment: No, but I see that you solved it. Nice! ... and good that you put it up as an answer too. It may help others in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for everyone, I just had to use mmap function to mmap my original executable file, mmap function can load the image and returns a pointer, then i could cast the output like this:

```
(const mach_header *) mmap(..)
```